# Error while copying to flash derive

Tags: flash, usb-drive, rsync, copy, cp

I tried to copy contents to usb(host system with ubuntu 16.04), this return  is no error and but  no "done" dialog box appears and havn't allocate any space in USB. it seems something like infinite loop with noting return. I also tried to use the "cp" command but its return noting .

```
sudo cp  source_file.iso /media/user/usb
```

when i tried same command for copying files like(.doc, .ppt .txt etc), its work fine, but dealing with files(have comparatively greater size) would not work.
i also tried this:

```
    sudo rsync --info=progress2 source_file.iso /media/user/usb

    3,139,436,544 100%  442.18MB/s    0:00:06 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
    rsync: mkstemp "/media/user/.usb.fMC7Bl" failed: Permission denied (13)
      3,139,436,544 100%  442.18MB/s    0:00:06 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
    rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.1]`
```

Comment: seems you do not get enough rights as normal user, have you try with sudo?

Comment: yes i try with sudo but same results